# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I am facing the following problem on one server only on another server or locally it is working properly.

I am using IIS6 Windows 2003. Is there any setting related problem?

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The
>   communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel,
>   cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
>   Server stack trace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout) Exception rethrown at [0]: at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a channel that has been faulted. You will need to recreate a new channel.

My toolkit has inbuilt support for this so that you can seamlessly make another call to the channel. It handles this scenario internally.

See http://neovolve.codeplex.com/releases/view/53499.

Comment: One thing you should do is check for missing fault contracts on your operations. You can throw a fault and it won't fault the channel as long as that fault contract is defined for the operation.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to find out what the real problem or issue is. For this set includeExceptionDetailInFaults to true as below in you service App.Config file:

serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"

Then you will get the real exception detail when you catch an exception. I was getting AccessDeniedException. So I ran this command from Power Shell:
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=Domainxxx\UserNamexxx. Problem solved.